# Error: no instance of overloaded function, in constructor (C++)

Tags: c++, class, function, constructor

I have a very weird problem... First of all, here are my class's files:

Show.h:

```
#ifndef SHOW
#define SHOW

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

class Show
{
private:
    std::string m_time;
    int m_serial
public:
    Show(const std::string &time, const int &serial);
    ~Show();
};
#endif
```

Show.c:

```
#include "Show.h"

Show::Show(const std::string &time,const int &serial)
{

}
```

As you can probably see, I only wrote the declaration of the constructor, when the visual studio underlined the second "Show" word in the Show.c file, and told me:

"void Show::Show(const std::string &time,const int &serial)

Show::Show()

Show::Show(const Show &)

Error: no instance of overloaded function "Show::Show" matches the specific type"

And when I stand with the mouse cursor over the constructor function in the Show.h file it looks like that function doesn't exists... I have written some classes in c++ before, and that is the first time anything like that happens to me... help please :(

Comment: `int m_serial` needs `;` after it.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you probably want to move your std header inclusions to your .c file (except for <string>).

Comment: There must have been more errors when you tried to compile, it always helps to look at _all_ the errors and not only the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put `;` after `m_serial` field variable. I believe this is the reason of the problem you have. Unfortunately many compilers do not give the exact reason of the problems like this, so you have to be careful with syntax rules.

Comment: lol That solved it right there. I sat on this thing for half a hour trying to figure it out and it was ";"... Many thanks :)